# How to use openssl to decrypt data encrypted by Java using AES

Tags: java, cryptography, openssl, aes, public-key-encryption

I am generating an AES public key and IV (Initialization Vector) in Java to encrypt data. I need to decrypt this using `openssl` command. Is this possible given that I store the AES Key and the IV on the disk?

Following is the encryption logic

```
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
    byte[] stringBytes = pass.getBytes();
    byte[] raw = cipher.doFinal(stringBytes);
    return Base64.encodeBase64String(raw);
```

Generating the AES Key

```
   SecretKey secret_key = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES").generateKey();
```

Generating the IV

```
   SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
   IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(random.generateSeed(16));
```

I am saving the IV and the AES Key in a file in a disk unencrypted. How do I now decrypt data using these two parameters using `openssl`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save them as hexadecimals and use e.g.

```
-K `cat key.hex` -iv `cat iv.hex`
```

so that's using the backticks instead of single quotation marks.

Comment: Is it possible to convert this SecretKey generated by java into hexadecimals?

Comment: getEncoded gives you a byte array of the raw key for AES. I'll leave it to you to find one of the countless snswers on how to convert a byte array to hex.